# How could I go about signing a response from API Gateway and Lambda?

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

We are designing an iOS game where some users will likely modify responses coming back from the serverless created backedend to cheat (via MITM fake certs). To help counteract this to some extent, we would like to have a signature included which will be hard to figure out. This implementation is all completed (and worked on Serverless-Offline but, we are having a hard time returning raw JSON from out of Lambda due to restrictions in API Gateway. We need to be able to have a snapshot of our JSON in order to ensure that the stringified version is in the same order when we take a checksum. Otherwise, it might be calculated differently on the iOS side where it is already a string prior to being inflated into an object.

Is there any possible way to return a string and not have API Gateway escape it?

For instance:

```
 callback(null, flattened_json_string);
```

yields a correct response on Serverless-Offline as it allows you to return a string. When actually hosted in API-Gateway, we get something escaped such as:

```
"{\"metadata\":{\"cmKey\":\"537d1a54916e56bac1d03478b18575e8c0c74d86\",\"cacheReady\":true,\"serverTime\":1467433541108},\"commands\":[]}"
```

I do know of ways to pass in a block like this, but I do not want it to be parsed and re-stringified and risk the order changing due to the checksum.

I am also aware that there are good javascript frameworks for getting hases of objects, but this is obviously not available client side on iOS.

Answer (score 1):

As of this writing, the author has an answered his own question, but there are some issues impacting the long-term stability of the solution.

The correct solution is to sort the keys (usually in lexical order) before encoding or after decoding the object, and assemble a hash (or, perhaps better, an HMAC?) of the canonical data -- sorted keys and values.  This makes signing and verification genuinely deterministic.

Using the wrong content type to make something work seems a little sketchy and fragile.

Also, it should be possible to eliminate the problem entirely, by expecting specific certificates to be presented by the application server -- certificate pinning, in a sense.   A malicious user with an MITM proxy and forged SSL certificate would have a computationally-impractical time impersonating your application server in that case.

[JSON Web Tokens](https://jwt.io/) also seem promising but perhaps not within the constraints of the question.

Comment: Is it possible to expect specific certificates from the server? In the case of the client wanting to intercept traffic and modify it, it is typically easy to trust an alternate root certificate that then signs the modified requests on the fly

Comment: If it's your SSL certificate, or one that you control, then you would know the [certificate thumbprint](http://security.stackexchange.com/a/35694/32112) which is for all practical purposes immune to tampering.  If you're using a generic endpoint like `https://example.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/` then the information should still be reasonably consistent and predictable, but is admittedly outside your control.

Answer (score 0):

After a few hours of work, the fix was actually fairly simple. I needed to change the response type to text/html and then stringify before returning.

With serverless, I set the following

```
"responseTemplates": {
        "text/plain": "$input.path('$')"
      }
```

In my code then:

```
callback(null, JSON.stringify(data));
```